# How can I concatenate to the end of a route using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel to create a project.

Is there a way to concatenate to the end of a url using `{{ route('routename') }}` in an `<a>` tag?

I created a list of thumbnail images that link to a collection of fullsize images using a foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <a href="{{ route('images') }}"> // link to full size image collection
        <img src="{{ $image->url }}">// thumbnail image
    </a>
@endforeach
```

`{{ route('image') }}` is a link to a paginated page that only contains one image per page.

so the url for the first image is `my.site/images?page=1`, the second is `my.site/images?page=2` and so on and so on.

I'm wanting to route the user to the correct `page=#` according to the thumbnail they click on so they don't have to start form the beginning of the fullsize images each time the click a link from the thumbnails.

Im thinking I can use a foreach loop to increment a variable by 1 and concatenate that on the end of each `href` to get the correct page number but I'm not sure how I can do this using Laravel?

Im wanting my resulting html to look like this

```
<a href="my.site/images?page=1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg"></a>
<a href="my.site/images?page=2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg"></a>
<a href="my.site/images?page=3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg"></a>
<a href="my.site/images?page=4"><img src="thumbnail4.jpg"></a>
<a href="my.site/images?page=5"><img src="thumbnail5.jpg"></a>
...
```

Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you found out yourself works perfectly fine, but there is a more elegant one. All parameters you pass as second argument that are no actual route parameters (like `{page}`) will be appended as query string.

```
{{ route('images', ['page' => $n]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by using this code

```
<?php $n = 1; ?>
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <a href="{{ route('images') . '?page=' . $n }}"> // link to full size image collection
        <img src="{{ $image->url }}">// thumbnail image
    </a>
    <?php $n++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It depends on your array/collection, but you could probably do ``@foreach ($images as $n => $image)`` and then ``'?page=' . $n+1``, that way you can get rid of the ``$n = 1`` and ``$n++`` lines. :)